# How to create Android Service Without interval in Appcelerator/titanium Android?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I want to create a service in appcelerator android where it starts when i click a download button and stops only if download is interrupted/fails or network is not present.

How can i achieve it? I have referred this article
 http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Service

I am following  this http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/File_Uploads_and_Downloads for downloading content (videos)

The other problem i face is ,i can't access the UI or the UI becomes almost non responsive, though i can scroll up and down. when download is in progress on android. This is what the UI looks like and i call a function on click of download button.

NOTE: Each element,light gray rectangle is like an accordian control, which toggles(expands and retracts) on click.

[image]

I have written a code like this in a `videoDownloader.js` file

```
 function downloadVideos(video_download_url){
       var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function() {
            // first, grab a "handle" to the file where you'll store the downloaded data
            var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'video.mp4');
            f.write(this.responseData); // write to the file

            timeout: 10000
    });
    xhr.open('GET',video_download_url);
    xhr.send();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [this module](http://gitt.io/component/dk.napp.downloadmanager) which handles everything for you.

Comment: It looks like its 64-bit, so should work on iOS and Android would be good as well then I guess. And Mads Moller (the author) is very good at responding to issues.